# String Compare [('3:1',....]

Tags: python

```
w=['3:1', '2:1', '1:1', '1:3']
```

how i can compare 3 with 1 and 2 with 1 the thing is first number is for team second for  opponent so i want to collect the point for matches

thanks

Comment: Split the strings at `:` and compare the list elements.

Comment: You need to write loop which iterates over your list, split every item (which is string) by colon, cast every part of splitted string to numbers and make comparison.

Comment: Why are you using a list of strings in the first place? Why not make everything numbers, like `[[3, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1], [1, 3]]`?

Comment: This how i got the question   you gave me a hint thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find the "matches" by using a list comprehension that holds `True` in the position if there is a match and `False` otherwise:

```
w=['3:1', '2:1', '1:1', '1:3'] 
output = [int(s.split(':')[0]) == int(s.split(':')[1]) for s in w]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[False, False, True, False]
```

From this you can modified to get any number of specific results.

Comment: Thank you Eli Harold

Answer (score -1):

You can use list comprehension, to iterate through each element and then check for the first element and the second element.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to do what you want:

```py
w=['3:1', '2:1', '1:1', '1:3']

team = []
opponent = []

for i in w:
    score = i.split(':')
    team.append(score[0])
    opponent.append(score[1])

print(team)
print(opponent)

['3', '2', '1', '1']
['1', '1', '1', '3']
```

The team's score will be stored in one variable and the opponent's in another